# How to filter uncategorised item in Outlook using vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook

While creating a macro which extracts some data from all uncategorised messages in outlook. i am able to get the data by using loop and checking the status of each mail in inbox however the count of mails in inbox is huge. so is there a way to filter only uncategorised item and then get the data from the filtered mails.

I tried the following code. However its not working for me.

```
Mailbox = Cells(k, 1).Value

Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(Mailbox).Folders("inbox")
Fldr.Items.Restrict ("[Category]=[]")
```

Is there a way with which i can speedup the macro.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  "Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement."

Comment: it doesnt work means the code does nothing. It just returns the entire items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This describes how to "[Filter Items that Do Not Have Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869279.aspx)"

```
Sub NullCategoryRestriction() 
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items 
    Dim Filter As String 

    'DASL Filter can test for null property. 
    'This will return all items that have no category. 
    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & _ 
     "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords" & _ 
     Chr(34) & " is null" 
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter) 
    Debug.Print oItems.Count 
End Sub
```